# django test app error - Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-testing

When I try to test any app with command (I noticed it when I tried to deploy myproject using fabric, which uses this command):

```
python manage.py test appname
```

I get this error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_finance', or 'no' to cancel
```

`syncdb` command seems to work. My database settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'finance',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'mydb123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 508, accepted):

When Django runs the test suite, it creates a new database, in your case `test_finance`. The postgres user with username `django` does not have permission to create a database, hence the error message.

When you run `migrate` or `syncdb`, Django does not try to create the `finance` database, so you don't get any errors.

You can add the createdb permission to the django user by running the following command in the postgres shell as a superuser (hat tip to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988495/postgres-user-create-database/8989722#8989722)).

```
=> ALTER USER django CREATEDB;
```

**Note:** The username used in the `ALTER USER <username> CREATEDB;` command needs to match the database user in your Django settings files. In this case, the original poster, had the user as `django` the above answer.

Comment: Though the OP used postgresql, if you are using mysql you will have the same error. You can fix it for mysql with:  => GRANT ALL ON \*.\* TO django@localhost;  I originally tried to only GRANT CREATE... but then could not SELECT or DROP the created database. This essentially makes your user a superuser, so be careful.

Comment: I experimented a little and found the minimum global priviledges are - Data: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, Structure: CREATE, ALTER, INDEX, DROP, Admin: REFERENCES. Not a super-user, but still pretty powerful, so use caution.

Comment: for my case I grant all priviliges to te test database, something like this: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_my_db.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 26):

I have found interesting solution to your problem. 
In fact for MySQL you can grant privileges for non-existing database.
So you can add name 'test_finance' for your test database in your settings:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'finance',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'mydb123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_finance',
        },
    }
}
```

start MySQL shell as the root user:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and now grant all privileges to this non-existing database in MySQL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_finance.* TO 'django'@'localhost';
```

Now Django will start tests without any problems.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT` in mysql shell. Any idea please?

Comment: As you can see I have started MySQL shell as the root user.

Comment: i love this answer. this doesn't make the user of django project become a database superuser

Answer (score 10):

If the database is **MySQL** then these two changes will get things done.

1.Open **`mysite/mysite/settings.py`**

Your database settings should have an additional `'TEST'` block as shown with **`projectname_test`**.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'USER': 'chandan',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'myproject_test',
        },
    }
}
```

2.Type the below command using **mysql command prompt** or **mysql workbench** to give all privilages to the user specified in **`settings.py`**

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myproject_test.* TO 'chandan'@'localhost';
```

Now you can run the below command:

```
python manage.py test polls
```

Comment: The question obviously uses Postgres as DBMS. What would *projectname_test* relate to?

Comment: @code-kobold 7,Yes,but i can see the same error in mysql as well.The value projectname_test is refer to name of project ex.in my answer it is myproject.

Comment: For MySQL use: grant all on myproject_test.* to 'chandan'@'%';

Answer (score 10):

In the case of Postgres, the user must have `createdb` permission.

```
ALTER ROLE miriam CREATEDB;
```

See this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I don't know why `GRANT PRIVILEGES` solutions don't work with ***Python 3.7.2***, ***Django 2.1.7***, and ***MySQL 5.6.23***.
So I decided to use SQLite as a `TEST` database:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'productiondb',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',   # 'django.db.backends.mysql'
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<pass>',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        },
        'TEST': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        },
    }
}
```

After that, the *tests* can run without trouble:

```
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: At first, this appeared to be a great idea. But I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I now see in the docs that specifying `ENGINE` in `TEST` [is not an option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#test). Also, I noticed you commented out the MySQL back end and added the connector. What's that?

Comment: You seem to have used different databases for the production and test environment. That may not be a good idea, and can cause database specific bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Wow so combining all of the answers here with a little tweaking finally got me to a working solution for docker-compose, django, and postgres...

First the postgres command given by noufal valapra is not correct (or maybe just not current), it should be:

```
ALTER USER docker WITH CREATEDB;
```

In the case of a docker-compose setup, this will go in the init.sql file, this is what mine looks like:

```
CREATE USER docker;
ALTER USER docker WITH CREATEDB;
CREATE DATABASE djangodb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE djangodb TO docker;
```

Then the Dockerfile for postgres looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:10.1-alpine
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Then the Django settings.py has this entry:

```
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    INTERNAL_DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
```

and the docker-compose looks like this:

version: '3.6'

services:

```
postgresdb:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-postgresdb
  volumes:
    - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

django:
  build:
    context: ../
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
  environment:
    - RDS_DB_NAME=djangodb
    - RDS_USERNAME=docker
    - RDS_PASSWORD=docker
    - RDS_HOSTNAME=postgresdb
    - RDS_PORT=5432

  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  depends_on:
    - postgresdb

volumes:
    postgresdata:
```

Answer (score 5):

Switch over to the postgres account on your server by typing:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

You can now access a Postgres prompt immediately by typing:

```
psql
```

Now type

```
ALTER USER username CREATEDB;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `docker-compose` what worked for me was the following:

```
ALTER ROLE username CREATEDB;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_database_name.* TO 'username';
```

or

```
ALTER ROLE username CREATEDB;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

My settings looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and my `docker-compose.yml` looks as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
      build: .
      command: './wait_for_db_and_start_server.sh'
      env_file: env_web
      working_dir: /project_name
      links:
        - db
      volumes:
        - .:/volume_name
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      depends_on:
        - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    env_file: env_db
    working_dir: /db
    volumes:
      - ./Dump.sql:/db/Dump.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem a while ago.
This is how I was able to solve it on django 3.10.6

First get into your dbshell via terminal by using this command

```
python3 manage.py dbshell
```

This will take you to your projects db ie if you have created one.
The other way to get to your db is:

```
sudo su postgres
```

then:

```
psql
```

This will take you to the default database. Then connect to your projects db by:

```
\c projectdb
```

At this point use this command to fix your error:

```
ALTER USER you CREATEDB;
```

Quit your db with '\q'; exit postgres with 'exit' then run:

```
python3 manage.py test app
```

The error will be fixed and your test will pass

```
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 1):

A superuser account is the easiest way to guarantee smooth testing. so a simpler way of making the `django` user su is to do `ALTER django WITH SUPERUSER` .

for more information https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html

Comment: `ALTER USER django WITH SUPERUSER`, you forgot the `USER` keyword. I tried to edit your post, but the edit que is full and won't free up.

Answer (score 1):

### Check the the actions in runtime and switch your database

```
import sys
TESTING = sys.argv[1:2] == ['test']
if TESTING==False:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
            'USER': config('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
            'PORT': ''
             }       
           }
else:
    DATABASES = {    
        'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "test_db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you put your test in suspended mode or as a backgrounded job. Try with `fg` command in bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a test database manually but putting the TEST key in your settings.py

Then fill pass the MIRROR key with value 'default' so you can test off of an exact replica of your default db, or whichever db you like.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'finance',
        'USER': 'django',
        'TEST': {
             'MIRROR': 'default',
        },
        'PASSWORD': 'mydb123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

You can also check the [advanced django postgres docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/)

Comment: It is a wrong approach because will use the real database to write persistent data into the database. Not being able to delete after.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue for

> pytest

I altered the django user permission so that it can create a test database while running python test cases.

**`ALTER USER USERNAME CREATEDB;`**

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests the user does not have sufficient permissions to create a database. Django creates a separate database during tests so that our original development database is not affected.

We might need to give the permissions via Postgres shell.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': "myuser",
    'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),

    'TEST': {
        'NAME': 'test_nofoobar',
    },
}
```

}

As the settings suggest, the name of the database user is **myuser** in this case. So, let's start the Postgres shell and give database creation permission.

```
sudo -u postgres psql


psql (14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-1.pgdg22.04+1))

postgres=# ALTER ROLE myuser CREATEDB;
Output: ALTER ROLE
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me,  I don't want to test against my production server ever:

```
local_settings.py

if 'PYTEST_RUN_CONFIG' in os.environ and os.environ['PYTEST_RUN_CONFIG']:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': settings.BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    } else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
             etc
        }
    }
```