# Travis: "Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database"

Tags: django, travis-ci

This is my `travis.yml` file:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
addons:
  postgresql: "9.3"
env:
  - SECRET_KEY=test DB_NAME=dbtest DB_USER=test DB_PASS=test
before_install:
  - export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.local
  - export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/builds/me/myrepo
install:
 - pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script:
 - psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE dbtest;'
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" -d dbtest
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology" -d dbtest
 - psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test';"
 - psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbtest to test;"
 - cd myapp && python manage.py migrate
script:
 - python manage.py test
```

But when I deploy the repo and Travis runs, it outputs this error:

```
10.96s$ pip install -r requirements.txt
0.24s$ psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE dbtest;'
0.77s$ psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" -d dbtest
0.09s$ psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology" -d dbtest
0.01s$ psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test';"
0.01s$ psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbtest to test;"
1.89s$ cd myapp && python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_dbtest', or 'no' to cancel:
```

I tried adding `psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER django CREATEDB;"` so that the `django` user would have permission to create a database, but that fails with:

```
ERROR:  role "django" does not exist
The command "psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER django CREATEDB;"" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

Comment: Did you define the user 'test' in settings file of your app ? The test database is created by the user specified by USER, so you’ll need to make sure that the given user account has sufficient privileges.

Comment: The settings file refers to the environment variable, which I set above. What I don't understand is that I can run `makemigrations` and `migrate` just fine (so must have adequate permissions to do that) but then I can't create the test database.

Comment: Got it: I had to make the user a superuser: `CREATE USER test WITH CREATEUSER PASSWORD 'test';` and then give the user permissions to create databases: `ALTER USER test CREATEDB;`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14186055

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer: I had to make the test user a superuser:

```
CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test';
```

and then give the user permissions to create databases:

```
ALTER USER test CREATEDB;
```