# Django / postgres setup for database creation, for running tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

My unittests are extending from `django.test.TestCase`. Using an SQLite3 backend, they are running fine.

I want to run them with a PostgreSQL backend, and the first thing that the tests are doing is to try and create a test database. This fails, since django has no permissions to do this. I want to configure PostgreSQL / django so that this operation is allowed, but I can not find any documentation on how to do this.

These are the settings used to *connect* to the database (`settings.py`):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'myppasss',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

When running the django application, I have always a pre-created database and user, so that django can connect.

I have two questions:

- What are the connection settings used to *create* the database, during unit test? My understanding is that the user that django is using to connect to the application database does not need to (and *should* not) have database creation rights.
- Where is all this described? The closest I have found is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#test) (`TEST` key in the `DATABASES` config parameter), but those settings mostly refer to Oracle databases, and have a different purpose.

Comment: Django will use the [same connection settings as in your settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) for tests, but will use a different database (by default `test_mydb`). In my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186055/django-test-app-error-got-an-error-creating-the-test-database-permission-deni/14186439#14186439), I gave instructions for how to add the createdb permission to a user. I don't know whether it's possible to restrict the permission so that the django user can only create the database `test_mydb`.

Comment: @Alasdair: This is a bit surprising for me but it works indeed. If you care to reply, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django test app error - Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186055/django-test-app-error-got-an-error-creating-the-test-database-permission-deni)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django will use [the same connection settings as in your settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) for tests, but will use a different database (by default, `test_mydb` where your regular database is `mydb`).

You can change the django user permissions to create databases in the psql shell. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186439/113962) for more info.

```
=> ALTER USER myuser CREATEDB;
```

I don't know whether it's possible to restrict the permission so that the django user can only create the database `test_mydb`.

Answer (score 4):

As of 2020 a superior option to giving Django the ability to create databases per other answers is just to use the `--keepdb` flag when running your tests:

```sh
$ ./manage.py test --keepdb
```

This will keep the same db around between runs, which is much faster and doesn't require giving your django user `CREATEDB` permissions. [More details here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb).

As @Alasdair previously noted, Django will [use the same settings as your normal database by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) but attempt to connect to or create a db at `test_<your-database-name>`. You can also customize the test DB's name with the `TEST` [dict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST) in your `DATABASE` settings.

Answer (score 0):

For production, I faced error when executing the accepted answer solution.
Something like this:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: cannot drop the currently open database`

For me, [according to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367697/django-cant-drop-database-psycopg2-operationalerror-cannot-drop-the-currently), I need to do:

```
ALTER USER <your_user> CREATEDB;
CREATE DATABASE postgres;
```

It needs to be `postgres` for the test to work without raising
`django.db.utils.OperationalError`