# Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the default database instead

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework

This community is my last resort for this problem, as I have been fighting with this for several hours now :( .

i work on a project where i try do the tests with docker-compose, with this command `docker-compose run runserver python3.6 manage.py test` but, I do not understand where it comes from and how resolve this. here are my mistakes

`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:267: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the default database instead.`

and

`psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.3) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

So, The docker-compose up working very well.

Here is the docker-compose.yml:

```html
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - path_volume
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  elasticsearch:
    image: path_elastic_search
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - path_volume

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

  redis:
    image: redis

  celery:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - elasticsearch
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    command: celery -A project worker --beat -l debug

  runserver:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/project
      - /opt/project/src
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - elasticsearch
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
      - celery
    command: python3.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

my dependencies:

- Django==1.11.5
- postgres==9

the response at command line `docker-compose ps` is:

```html
            Name                          Command                State                                          Ports                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datablitzapi_celery_1          celery -A datablitz worker ...   Up                                                                                        
datablitzapi_elasticsearch_1   /bin/bash bin/es-docker          Up         0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                               
datablitzapi_postgres_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up         0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                                         
datablitzapi_rabbitmq_1        docker-entrypoint.sh rabbi ...   Up         0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp, 25672/tcp, 4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp
datablitzapi_redis_1           docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up         6379/tcp                                                                       
datablitzapi_runserver_1       python3.6 manage.py runser ...   Exit 255   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

Comment: have you tried using links instead of dependes_on only?

Comment: Can you confirm that the postgres docker container is running? If you edit your question with the output of `docker ps` or `docker-compose ps` that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening because Django expecting the database will be up and running (Read for Connections)

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.3) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What you need is to add some delay mechanism to make Django wait until your PostgreSQL container is actually ready to receive connections. For more details you can take a look at [my answer in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033751/2336650), it was about MySQL and same scenario applies to PostgreSQL.

Regarding this issue and according to [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367698/2336650), it might be also because of the same reason

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py:267: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the default database instead.
```

So start by implementing the `wait-for-it` which explained at the first link and then try again