# Can't run test on the Python/Django application

Tags: python, django

Well I have already grant the user to 'CREATEDB'.

but when I run the test using `python manage.py test`

I got this error,

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'... Got an error creating
the test database: permission denied to create database
```

This is my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'my_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST' : {
            'NAME': 'test_my_db'
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Things we probably need to know:

1) What backend?
2) What grant did you give the database user?
3) Can it connect to the default db (i.e. is there a password problem here)?

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: posible dublicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186055/django-test-app-error-got-an-error-creating-the-test-database-permission-deni]

Comment: Does `python manage.py migrate` work?