# Got an error creating the test database - django, docker, mysql

Tags: mysql, django, docker-compose

I have an issue with creating test database. I use mysql for db and docker compose.

I have no problem running docker containers with docker-compose, but when I run test it spits this error message.

Note that the name of django service is web, and mysql service is db.

```
$ docker-compose run --rm web sh -c "python manage.py test"
Creating sociallogin_web_run ... done
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: (1044, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'%' to database 'test_mydb'")
```

my `docker-compose.yml`:
version: "3.9"

```
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: 
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    # ports:
    #   - "3306:3306"
    # volumes:
    #   - data:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py makemigrations && 
             python manage.py migrate && 
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env

# volumes:
#   data:
```

my `.env` file looks like this:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
MYSQL_USER=exampleuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD=examplepass
MYSQL_DATABASE=exampledb
MYSQL_PORT=3306
SECRET_KEY=exmaple_random_characters
```

DATABASES in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_mydb',
        }
    }
}
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186055/django-test-app-error-got-an-error-creating-the-test-database-permission-deni), and I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45131868/11790764). It didn't help me.

Anyone who's been stuck at similiar problem?

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is issue is not related django app, this is look like basic mysql error where you try to create/access database with that user which is not have permission for create/manage database, please test it again via root user of database.

You can visit on this url [ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db) for.

Answer (score 4):

As [K.D Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67353468/11790764) mentioned, It was indeed mysql user permission problem.

## In short, use root user when initializing mysql container.

Not sure what keeps making separate user from making test though. Because [mysql docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) says

> MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
> These variables are optional, used in conjunction to create a new user and to set that user's password. This user will be granted superuser permissions (see above) for the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable. Both variables are required for a user to be created.

, **doesn't this mean if I create user and password then it has superuser permissions like creating database as well?** Not sure why it has permission issue.

### Anyway, below is what I changed.

Do note that there is no need to use this mechanism to create the root superuser, that user gets created by default with the password specified by the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable.

I changed my `DATABASES` setting as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PORT'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('MYSQL_HOST'),
    }
}
```

So basically I removed `USER` key and updated `PASSWORD` with `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, not `MYSQL_PASSWORD` tied to `MYSQL_USER` that I initiated my container with.

my `.env` file has a change like this:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabasename
MYSQL_PORT=3306
MYSQL_HOST=db
SECRET_KEY=random_secret_key_that_has_no_dollar_sign
```

my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: 
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    # volumes:
    #   - data:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
             python manage.py makemigrations && 
             python manage.py migrate && 
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env

# volumes:
#   data:
```

Interestingly as for `ports` part, notice that I set `3308:3306`. Since I already have another running mysql container that is running with default port `3306`, When I use ports `3306:3306`, it didn't work. So I only changed outer port into `3308` and inner port `3306`. Since django app communicates with inner port, .env file's port number stays put as 3306.

Comment: It isn't recommended to run migrations before starting the app, this leads to problems. Always decouple running migrations from server startup, this is well documented.

Comment: Can you share the section where such is documented please? @robvdl

Comment: Here is a link explaining why you should decouple your migrate up from app startup. Basically if you switch to an older branch or a newer branch, you don't always want it to migrate up. That leads to trouble.

https://pythonspeed.com/articles/schema-migrations-server-startup/

Comment: Will look into it. Thanks @robvdl